# C++ text argument to constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

> cont = cont;

I don't know how to convert  cont to cont type pointer.

If I do like this : this->cont = (char*)cont;

In deconstructor I have exception error.

So is it good to convert const char to char* or I need to do better (but how?) ?

And I have to have dynamic allocate.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
class Matrix {
private:
    int x;
    char *cont;
public:
    Matrix(){
        cout << "aa";
    }
    Matrix(const char *cont) {
        this->cont = cont;
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        delete cont;
    }


};

int main()
{
    Matrix("__TEXT__");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `delete` what you `new` - there is no `new` so you cannot use `delete`

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: Also don't ever cast away `const` - 99% of the time it's plain wrong (including here)

Answer (score 1):

```
this->cont = cont;
```

Is "wrong", as in, it doesn't actually copy the data; that's also why `delete` in your destructor if failing. Your answer mentions "I have to have dynamic allocate.", so I presume that's what you actually wanted. In this case, simply use `std::string`:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int x;
    std::string cont;           // <--- changed type
public:
    Matrix(){
        cout << "aa";
    }
    Matrix(const char *cont)
    : cont(cont) {              // <--- this actually copies
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to allocate space for a pointer to char using new .
And in the destructor deallocate that space " delete [] cont " instead of "delete cont" . 
but it will be a good choice to use std::string instead of char []